# KVM - Which Web Based management to use?

Tags: linux, debian, kvm

I would like to became an Expert of managing KVM on debian squeeze.

I still use virt-manager. Yes, it is easy and quiet safe and quick for me.

I tried a lot of web based management UI and non of them was good enough like virt-manager.

You know, I'm one of those guys, who used to have VMware before, where 90% of managing is clicking.

My questions :

1) Are there any CLI "interactive" utility like mc (midnight commander) or something how to control KVM ? (ON/OFF VMs, increasing memmory, reseting VMs, adding virtual hardware, adding new disks, and so on...)

2) Could you recommend me some Web based management UI for KVM on debian squeeze?
 Did you see VMware server 2? There is web management. I know it was slow, but it is fine, when you are somewhere without terminal. (for example on android with web browser)
I tried a lots of them, but nothing i tried was working.

3) What tutorials could you recommend me to improve myself in commands to control virsh, kvm and so on? Google is full of low quality tutorials with mistakes and misunderstandings. I need something for debian.

4) Could you recommend me some tutorials how to improve performance for KVM? Google is full of a lot of tutorials, but I need some recommendations from real experts, who knows, how to improve it.

5) How to improve security of KVM? Can solve this problem some Web based UI? (for example accounting, user management ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q1&2**

For web-based KVM manager, you can try [Proxmox](http://www.proxmox.com/). Instruction for Debian Squeeze is [here](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_Squeeze).

It has command-line tools, but not text-based -- menu-driven.

**Q3**

You should setup a small environment and try it out. Then set out a goal and implement it.

**Q4**

There is no accurate answer/tutorial for this. How tunable your KVM server/client is really depends on how many resources (cpu/ram/storage) are available.

**Q5**

Again, this depends on your environment and it is multi-layers/devices, e.g. routers, firewall, ip-tables, password policy, access policy, etc. I am not aware of a single GUI, web-based or not, that can handle all of that including the KVM. (OK, there is [cloudmin](http://www.webmin.com/cloudmin.html), but I have no experience with that at all)

Comment: to Q4: I have 24 GB RAM, 3x WD RE4 in RAID 5 (+1 spare), Quad core Athlon II x4 CPU.  Thank you

Comment: Base on your spec., the weak point (relatively) maybe your storage throughput. You can check out my answer to another question [here](http://serverfault.com/a/460558/138643).

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried **[Kimchi](https://kimchi-project.github.io/kimchi/downloads/)**? is the most user friendly open-source web front end on KVM and it's sponsored by IBM.

[image: Main Dashboard]

[image: Thumbnail view]

[image: Summary View]

Disclaimer : I am not affiliated in anyway with Kimchi. I just like its user friendliness.

Comment: The project seems really dead - 300 open issues, open pull requests, ... shame. It looked nice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new Enterprise-level KVM and AV/IT system management called [Boxilla](http://www.black-box.eu/boxilla) which features a comprehensive and centralised command centre, which provides top performance, ease of use and security.

It provides the ability to manage high-performance KVM, KVM over IP, virtualized end-points, and various AV/IT devices on one centralised command centre, empowers administrators to manage multi-environment KVM and AV/IT deployments using a powerful web-enabled and common user-interface. You can find more about it here: https://www.blackbox.co.uk/gb-gb/page/37929/Solutions-Industries/Technology-Products/KVM-Switching-and-Extension/Centralised-KVM-AV-Manager-Boxilla

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend [Ispserver](http://ispsystem.com/en/software/vmmanager). If you follow the link you will find instructions on installing and configuring the KVM web interface on Debian.

The KVM installation guide might not very detailed but at least give or provide ideas regarding the installation and configuration process.

Answer (score -5):

Experts use CLIs. Not GUIs. That is even true for expert Windows-admins.

No, GUIs still improve, but self-written scripts are way faster and do what you want.

Improve performance in KVM? Throw it away.

This is just a hint from a XEN-PV-expert. Only LXC (or other containers) or chroot-based solutions are faster.

Comment: Well chroot-based solutions and containers have too much limitations for me, so they are useless for me. I was already thinking about scripts, but if you want to demonstrate power and possibilities, you want to demonstrate it on graphs, tabs and statistical data from web management UI. Next one is, how to access screen of VMs without any client? Web based solution is the answer, when SSH on VMs fails.

Comment: @Mirra normally "my" VMs are servers - with no need of GUI or even runlevel 5. So a serial console is all I need. In normal operations an X11 via ssh is enough. The best GUIs I know of do an SSH-tunnel to the VM-server and then display a VNC-session to a port dedicated to a certain VM (bound to localhost on that server). Most (current) VM-security-holes are based on RAM-attacks on simulated graphic cards.

Comment: Real experts don't care if it's GUI or CLI, whatever gets the job done, only purists care if its CLI only. I care about getting the job done that meets all the criteria.

Comment: I tought the same, and then I tried xen. First, I needed to recompile my kernel. Second, I had no more access to cooling control and temperature data from dom0. Third, I found the bullshit "reasoning" of a Xen developer that it should not be done. Fourth: **it was slower than my Qemu VMs**. Fifth: **even my dom0 was so slow like a VM (because it is)**. While I still like the Xen concept and I believe this should be done, the practice is that kvm is well-optimized and Xen is... well... sorry to say but imho it is a crap.

Comment: Yeah, and sixth: I needed to even recompile xen to work, I can not remember the cause but it was probably some kernel incompatibility. It was a huge pain.